# submit button open new window and close parent window?

Tags: html, forms, authentication

i've basically got a login form, it pops up in a css box asking the user to login. i was having the problem that once the user clicked submit they were being taken to the login window within the css box so made the submit button open a blank/new window.

The problem i have now though is the parent window stays open with the users login details. For security i'd really like to get rid of this, so is there a way i can close the parent window on the launch of the new one? Or even set it so that the page refreshes after the submit button is pressed to clear the css box?

Thanks

Here's what i've got so far:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" target="_blank"  >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" target="_top"  >
```

This will send the form to the parent window, which should completely remove the login box, and reload the parent page as well.

Comment: @EricHaze Please accept the answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use js

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function add_tab2(){
   var newTab = gBrowser.addTab('http://www.google.com');
   newTab.label = "MyTab";
   newTab.id = "MyTab";
   gBrowser.selectedTab = newTab;
   aDoc = document.getElementById("MyTab");
   // do something with aDoc here
   window.close();
}
</script>
```